# Can't update database in October CMS

Tags: octobercms

Hope, it's my last question about October CMS :)

I need to add some columns to the existing table called "foo_bar_experts".
But when i'm saving my migration file there is an error popping

> SQLSTATE[42701]: Duplicate column: 7 ERROR:  column "event_id" of relation "agm_dalshe_events_skills" already exists (SQL: alter table "agm_dalshe_events_skills" add column "event_id" integer not null, add column "skill_id" integer not null)

I tried to delete this table, create new but this error haunting me, and I can't actually do nothing in my database.

Can you suggest any ideas what the hell is happening there? Thanks in advance.

Comment: its because your migration files are generated differently and may be you changed table by your self so created conflict. first migration file add `event_id` then again it trying to add once again `event_id`

Comment: so suggestion `go to > updates` folder check each file and delete the line where it is adding `event_id` first one [across multiple files] so there is only code which `can add single time event_id`. do it smartly so at last you have both fields[`event_id , skill_id`] only once, then just uninstall plugin delete all `tables from db related to plugin` [if you have data export it]. now again install plugin then `import your data again` may be that will solve your problem.

Comment: nice to hear, you solved your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Solution `go to > updates folder` of your plugin.

> check each file and delete the line where it is adding `event_id first time` [across multiple files] so there should only code remain in which `it add single time event_id`.

do it `smartly` so at last you have both `fields[event_id , skill_id] only once`,

> Then just uninstall plugin delete all tables from db related to plugin **[if you have data export it]**. now again install plugin then **import your data again** may be that will solve your problem.

if any doubt please comment.